# Turn a list into a matrix

Tags: prolog

I worked all afternoon on a simple thing but cannot seem to get it right for some reason : how to turn a list into a matrix of given width.

Example :
I got a list such as

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9, 0]
```

and want to create a matrix such as

```
[[1, 3],
 [5, 7],
 [6, 8],
 [9, 0]]
```

through a predicate

```
list2matrix/3 : list2matrix(List, Size_of_Rows, Matrix).
```

In this example used like :

```
list2matrix([1, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9, 0], 2, Matrix).
```

The predicate should fail if the length of the list is not a multiple of the size of the rows.

I decided not to post my work since I think I got it so wrong that it would not help me to get correction on it ;(

Thanks by advance if you can propose any leads about how to deal with such a problem.

Comment: Your problem statement is incomplete. Shall `list2matrix([1, 3, 5], 2, Matrix)` succeed or fail? And in case of success, shall `[5]` be dropped or extended to `[5,_]` or whatever other value.

Comment: let's say it'd fail, thanks for pointing that out. Since I intend on using it on list with square lengthes I didn't precise ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide the problem in two parts.
The first building block would be to build a row of N elements. That is to take the input list and split it in two lists, one will have exactly N elements (the row) and the other is the remaining of the input list.

The second building block would be to build the matrix which is made of rows.

```
list_to_matrix([], _, []).
list_to_matrix(List, Size, [Row|Matrix]):-
  list_to_matrix_row(List, Size, Row, Tail),
  list_to_matrix(Tail, Size, Matrix).

list_to_matrix_row(Tail, 0, [], Tail).
list_to_matrix_row([Item|List], Size, [Item|Row], Tail):-
  NSize is Size-1,
  list_to_matrix_row(List, NSize, Row, Tail).
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'm trying to understand it and will test it soon, I'll comment after that :)

Comment: Ok ok, I read it and understood it quite easily, though I still think I'd have had a hard time finding a solution by myself :(

I just added :- !. to cut backtracking after each first choice so that it's deterministic and now I have what I wanted, thank you a lot :)

Comment: Your `list_to_matrix_row` can be simplified to `list_to_matrix_row(L, RowLen, Row, Rest) :- length(Row, RowLen), append(Row, Rest, L).`

Comment: You 're right!. However I believe it is easier to understand with this recursive procedure.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, I thought I'd mention the code I finally wrote :

```
length_(Length, List) :- length(List, Length).

list2matrix(List, RowSize, Matrix) :-
    length(List, L),
    HowManyRows is L div RowSize,
    length(Matrix, HowManyRows),
    maplist(length_(RowSize), Matrix),
    append(Matrix, List).
```

It's more high order oriented and funnier to read I guess :)

Comment: Interesting! With [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl) you could write `maplist({RowSize}+\Xs^length(Xs,RowSize), Matrix)` instead of using an auxiliary definition. See [this intro](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord).

Answer (score 1):

Look for a pattern in your desired outcome.
That means pair numbers will be allocated as the second number in each pair and non pairs will be in first place each time.
Create a bi dimensional array and assign non pair positions to sub index "a"
and pairs to "b".

As you could see "i" is an index for an array, a multidimensional array.
i[a][b]

You need to iterate through both arrays in order to accomplish this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the problem I got when doing it this way is that it's fine for 2 as width of the matrix but not for any number instead of 2. In my case I'm interested in particular in transforming a list whose length is 81 into a 9*9 matrix. I'd like the resulting predicate to be size-hardcoding free but if 9 gotta be hardcoded then it's ok !