# Prolog - Matrix to list

Tags: list, recursion, matrix, prolog

There was a question to turn a list (of any length) to a matrix here (see link at the bottom), but I'd like to do the opposite, turn a matrix into a list, recursively.

```
Matrix = [[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]
```

define predicate   :

```
matrixToList(MyMatrix,NewList)
```

where `NewList = [a,b,c,d,e,f].`

Can anyone please help?
Thank you.

[Turn a list into a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999438/turn-a-list-into-a-matrix)

Comment: Can you just [`flatten/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=flatten/2) the list?

Comment: I'm wondering, are all of the Prolog classes these days teaching and proliferating the use of camel case for Prolog functor names? As @aBathologist suggests, `matrix_to_list(MyMatrix, NewList) :- flatten(MyMatrix, NewList).` would be the cleanest implementation.

Comment: @mbratch I don't think it is on purpose, most likely a habit from Java programming. If you follow the coding conventions nicely described here: http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2899 it would then be also `My_Matrix` or even `My_matrix`.

Comment: @Boris you may be right. The most popular languages encourage it and it spills over. I find myself using it for variable names in Prolog, but not with functors.

Comment: @aBathologist: Using `flatten/2` is definitely a bad idea: A matrix of matrices of integers would thus be flattened to a list of integers and not a list of matrices of integers.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9787502/772868)

Comment: @false that makes sense. I suppose my view was too limited to the specific case.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for the same problem, but yes, you can also use flatten

```
getAllElements([],[]).
getAllElements([H|T], ElementsList) :- getAllElements(T, NewElementsList),
                                       append(NewElementsList, H, ElementsList).
```