# how to turn a list of 2 lists into a 2 columns df in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this list (which is created using append function twice):

```
['2017-04-03.csv', 108.0, '2017-04-04.csv', -12.0]
```

(it's much longer and length can very) and when using `results = pd.DataFrame({'col':results})`
I get the following:

```
              col
0  2017-04-03.csv
1             108
2  2017-04-04.csv
3             -12
```

I am looking to get:

```
                  col
2017-04-03.csv   108
2017-04-04.csv   -12
```

I checked the solutions offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175382/python-create-a-pandas-data-frame-from-a-list), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636344/read-flat-list-into-multidimensional-array-matrix-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999438/turn-a-list-into-a-matrix) but they all not work as I expect/need.
thanks

Comment: Can you provide a little context on how the list is created? There may be a better solution than what I've currently offered you, based on what you'e doing right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slicing is your friend -

```
pd.DataFrame(results[1::2], index=results[::2], columns=['col'])

                  col
2017-04-03.csv  108.0
2017-04-04.csv  -12.0
```

Even indexed elements form the index, and odd indexed elements form the column values.

Comment: If i have more columns, lets say 5, how can I use the same to create a split into columns?

Comment: @Giladbi I think it should be possible to generalise with a list comprehension... slice over [i::5] for i in range(1,5), if that makes sense.

Comment: I didn't mange to do this. I assume my pandas knowledge is lucking.